# How to use instance-variable or param after a format.js on controller - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in rails and coding in general:

```rb
def startoffers
  id = params[:id]
  @id = params[:id]
  @product = Product.find(id)
  if @product.present?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render "search/startoffers"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

So, what this does is sending you to a JS that will hide/unhide a part html, and will also have it;s own JS there. My issue is that I can't seem to send a parameter or instance variable to be used there:

```js
$("#startoffers").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'search/startoffers')%>").show();
$("#close-offer").on("click",function(){
  $("#startoffers").hide();  
});
$("#oneclick").on("click",function(id){
  var product_id = id;
  window.location.href = "/offers/chat/" + product_id;
});
```

Partial:

```html
</div class="btn-success"> <a id="oneclick" data-id="<%= @product.id %>">Click Here</a> </div>
```

I can't seem to be able to use id correctly. When redirected I'm redirected to:

http://localhost:3000/offers/chat/[object%20Object]

Comment: can you post what's in `search/startoffers` partial ?

Comment: Main part is:     </div class="btn-success">
    <a id="oneclick" data-id="<%= @product.id %>">Click Here</a>
    </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to use the instance variable in `js.erb` view templates

```
alert("<%= @product.id %>");
```

It will print the `id` of the `@product` in alert box.

Comment: That was it, I didn't do the simple relation that it would work just like in html.erb. Thanks!